# Selenium java - Pass boolean parameter from pageObjects Common function

Tags: java, selenium, parameters, selenium-webdriver, testng

In my selenium test case, I have many items to verify (eg. `toCheck_isUserLogin`, `toCheck_isGenderChkbxExists` etc).

I have group this checking into pageObjects common function for reusable purpose.
Other than write each checking item `Pass/Fail`, I have a column in excel to specify overall test result (Pass/Fail)

Assume one of my test case, `gender checkbox` is not found on the page, It should  write test result `fail` to column `'COL_IS_GENDER_CHKBX_EXISTS'`.

Also It should pass `Testfail=true` into main script so at `@AfterMethod` the overall test result for the test case will be `fail` since one of the verify items failed.

After I move the code to pageObject, I'm not able to pass `Testfail` value to main test script, could anyone help me to check whats wrong
with my code, thanks.

`// Selenium Main Test Script`

```
    public class MyTestCase_01 extends SuiteRBase{
    Read_XLS FilePath_TestResult = null;
    static boolean TestCasePass = true; 
    static boolean Testskip = false;
    static boolean Testfail = false;
    static int DataSet = -1;
    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void checkCaseToRun() throws IOException{

        init(); 
        FilePath_TestResult = MyTestCase_01_TestResult;
        TestCaseName = this.getClass().getSimpleName(); 
        // code..   
    }

    @Test(dataProvider="MyTestCase_01Data")
    public void MyTestCase_01Test(String ColTestCaseName, String ColUsername, String ColPassword, String ColGender) throws Exception{

        // code...      
        try{

            Login_Page.toCheck_isUserLogin(FilePath_TestResult, TestCaseName, DataSet+1, Testfail);  

            // This was my code before move it into pageObjects Login_Page.java
        /*  Boolean isGenderChkbxExists = driver.findElements(By.xpath(Object.getProperty("verify_isGenderChkbxExists"))).size()!= 0;
            if (isGenderChkbxExists == true){
                SuiteUtility.WriteResultUtility(FilePath_TestResult, TestCaseName, Constant.COL_IS_GENDER_CHKBX_EXISTS,
                    DataSet+1, Constant.KEYWORD_PASS);
                    Testfail = false; 
            }else{
                SuiteUtility.WriteResultUtility(FilePath_TestResult, TestCaseName, Constant.COL_IS_GENDER_CHKBX_EXISTS,
                    DataSet+1, Constant.KEYWORD_FAIL);
                    Testfail=true;
            }   */
            Register_Page.toCheck_isGenderChkbxExists(FilePath_TestResult, TestCaseName, DataSet+1, Testfail);          

        }catch(Exception e){
            Testfail = true;
            throw (e);
        }

        if(Testfail){
            // At last, test data assertion failure will be reported In testNG reports and It will mark your test data, test case and test suite as fail.
            s_assert.assertAll();       
        }
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void reporterDataResults() throws Exception{     
        if(Testskip){
            Add_Log.info(TestCaseName+" : Reporting test data set line "+(DataSet+1)+" as SKIP In excel.");
            // If found Testskip = true, Result will be reported as SKIP against data set line In excel sheet.
            SuiteUtility.WriteResultUtility(FilePath, TestCaseName, "Pass/Fail/Skip", DataSet+1, Constant.KEYWORD_SKIP);
        }
        else if(Testfail){
            Add_Log.info(TestCaseName+" : Reporting test data set line "+(DataSet+1)+" as FAIL In excel.");
            // To make object reference null after reporting In report.
            s_assert = null;
            // Set TestCasePass = false to report test case as fail In excel sheet.
            TestCasePass=false; 
            // If found Testfail = true, Result will be reported as FAIL against data set line In excel sheet.
            SuiteUtility.WriteResultUtility(FilePath, TestCaseName, "Pass/Fail/Skip", DataSet+1, Constant.KEYWORD_FAIL);
        }else{
            Add_Log.info(TestCaseName+" : Reporting test data set line "+(DataSet+1)+" as PASS In excel.");
            // If found Testskip = false and Testfail = false, Result will be reported as PASS against data set line In excel sheet.
            SuiteUtility.WriteResultUtility(FilePath, TestCaseName, "Pass/Fail/Skip", DataSet+1, Constant.KEYWORD_PASS);            
        }
        // At last make both flags as false for next data set.
        Testskip=false;
        Testfail=false;
    }   
}
```

`// pageObjects Login_Page.java`

```
public class Login_Page extends BaseClass{

    private static WebElement element = null;
    static boolean Testfail = false;

    public Login_Page(WebDriver driver){
            super(driver);
    }

    public static WebElement toCheck_isUserLogin(Read_XLS xls, String sheetName, int rowNum, Boolean Testfail) throws Exception{
        try{
            Boolean isUserLogin = driver.findElements(By.xpath(Object.getProperty("verify_isUserLogin"))).size()!= 0;               
            if (isUserLogin == true){
                SuiteUtility.WriteResultUtility(xls, sheetName, Constant.COL_IS_USER_LOGIN, rowNum, Constant.KEYWORD_PASS);
                Testfail = false;                   
            }else{
                SuiteUtility.WriteResultUtility(xls, sheetName, Constant.COL_IS_USER_LOGIN, rowNum, Constant.KEYWORD_FAIL);

                // Pass testfail true to main script so at @AfterMethod it will write overall test result 'fail'
                Testfail = true;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw(e);
        }
        return element;
    }

    public static WebElement toCheck_isGenderChkbxExists(Read_XLS xls, String sheetName, int rowNum, Boolean Testfail) throws Exception{
        try{
            Boolean isGenderChkbxExists = driver.findElements(By.xpath(Object.getProperty("verify_isGenderChkbxExists"))).size()!= 0;
            if (isGenderChkbxExists == true){
                SuiteUtility.WriteResultUtility(xls, sheetName, Constant.COL_IS_GENDER_CHKBX_EXISTS, rowNum, Constant.KEYWORD_PASS);
                    Testfail = false; 
            }else{
                // write into column 'COL_IS_GENDER_CHKBX_EXISTS' fail
                SuiteUtility.WriteResultUtility(xls, sheetName, Constant.COL_IS_GENDER_CHKBX_EXISTS, rowNum, Constant.KEYWORD_FAIL);

                // Pass testfail true to main script so at @AfterMethod it will write overall test result 'fail'
                Testfail=true;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw(e);
        }
        return element;
    }
}
```

Pls let's me know if need more information, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Normally in PageObjects , we dont have any assertions. Your PageObject can be modified to be like this -

```
public static List<WebElement> getUserLogin(Read_XLS xls, String sheetName, int rowNum, Boolean Testfail) throws Exception{
        try{
            return driver.findElements(By.xpath(Object.getProperty("verify_isUserLogin")));            

    }
```

And do your assertions in Main test class -

```
   List<WebElement> elements=   Login_Page.getUserLogin(FilePath_TestResult, TestCaseName, DataSet+1, Testfail);  

if(elements.size())!=0{
Testfail =false;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Gosaka, thanks for your reply, after keyin `elements` dot, there is no `size` word populated, it only have `getSize` and will get msg `Incompatible operand types Dimension and int`

Comment: I have edited now.. Basically what I was trying to convey was that in your PageClass you return driver.findElements(By.xpath(Object.getProperty("verify_isUserLogin"))). This will give you List<WebElement> and in your main Test class , get this list and you will get your size. I did not give the exact code. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hi Gosaka, thanks for your help, but I'm not able to produce the expected results as `if(elements.size())!=0{Testfail =false;}` always get overall result `Pass`. Is there anyway I can pass `testfail` value from `pageObjects` to main script? thanks.

Comment: Hi Gosaka, how about if I want to verify is a checkbox get `checked`. In `List<WebElement>` I can't find element.`isSelected`

Comment: You have to iterate through the list and get individual WebElement. Once you get the WebElement object you should be able to do element.isSelected